# Laravel 6+ Uniq id generation Only in number with Additional Logic

Tags: php, laravel, random, laravel-6

I am generating A uniqid with `time()` function Thats is about 10 digits.. i want a uniq no where i can store 18 digits no only! For these  i want to generate `rand(3 digit)` + `rand(3 digits)` + `rand(2 digits)` ..
I have Few questions
1. Is there a chance to collision 
2. Is the 10 digits time() can increase into 11 or 12
3. If it increases Than i want to build a logic where i can dynamically generate the random no Like =>
18(Max) - if 10 (time) => then 3+3+2
if(11) then 3+2+2 && if(12) then 3+3 
If it is possible then Please Guide me! 
Other Suggetions Also welcome!

Comment: Sorry, you must have misunderstood.  I meant to answer the six questions I give (numbered 1 through 6) in "Unique Random Identifiers", and write your answers to those questions here.

Comment: :( np i will do that

Comment: @PeterO. can u tell me please possibility of `time()` [10] to 11 or 12 digits ???

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `bin2hex(random_bytes(9))` to generate random identifiers.  But note that these identifiers can contain letters from A to F in addition to digits.

But note that random numbers are generally not enough to ensure uniqueness, although `bin2hex(random_bytes(9))` will be unique with overwhelming probability.  And there are several other things to consider, such as:

- Whether identifiers have to be hard to guess, or merely "look random".
- Whether identifiers are the only thing that grants access to what they identify.

The best way to generate unique identifiers will depend on these and other questions, which I give in the section "[Unique Random Identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers)". You should edit your question post with the answers to the six questions I give in that section; the answers will further suggest what kind of identifiers to use.

Comment: Should i post your Questions Too with the answers??

Comment: Yes you should.